# CRM Custom Action Parameter

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, workflow-activity

Currently I'm working with Dynamics CRM 2015 specially: Custom Actions

I'm able to start my custom action which will create an Invoice from a account.

But I'd like to get that invoice in my code...

I'm starting the "WorkFlow" with

```
Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.ExecuteWorkflowRequest request = new Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Messages.ExecuteWorkflowRequest()
{
    WorkflowId = WorflowId,
    EntityId = xEntity.Id
};    
ExecuteWorkflowResponse xOrganizationResponse = (ExecuteWorkflowResponse)orgSvcContext.Execute(request)
```

But than the xOrganizationResponse just has 1 attribute which is GUID Empty..

Does anyone knows how to get the Output parameter specified in the custom action?

Here's a screenshot of my custom action:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was now able to get the output parameter like

```
OrganizationRequest request = new OrganizationRequest("ise_account_newinvoice_")
request.Parameters.Add("Target", xAccountReference);
request.Parameters.Add("invoicenumber", strInvoiceNumber);

OrganizationResponse xResponse = orgSvcContext.Execute(request);
```

I just needed tho had the "Target" as is in the request.

Comment: Hi Unlockedluca, did you also have to add the Target parameter to the process too? Are you able to assist with this query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366481/crm-2013-custom-action-plugin-not-firing