# CRM 2013 Custom Action Plugin not firing

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Wondering if someone could give me a bit of help.

I am trying to use custom actions from CRM 2013, what I have is a custom action "Clone" defined as below.

[image]

I have a very simple clone record plugin that clones the passed in target entity and returns the new entity as an output parameter.

[image]

The plugin is registered to fire on the Custom action,  my plan was to fire this from JavaScript but the plugin never fired so for the time being to test I have been firing this from another plugin. Using the below code.

The other plugin fires and hits the call to the execute method but the other plugin never seems to fire and the response is always null.

[image]

If anyone has any ideas what I am missing that would be great.

Thanks in advance chaps

Antony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What just get in my mind is that you have to write your `OrganizationRequest("name_of_CustomAction")` exactly the same way as you have written named your CA `("..._CLONE")`

Have you already tried debugging your PLUGIN ? Do that with the [Plugin Registration Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh237515%28v=crm.6%29.aspx) from Microsoft.
If you've already got this tool just try doing it exactly like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2778280)(Step-By-Step Guide how to debug your plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have tried executing the custom action by its name with and without the publisher prefix and it still doesnt work. I have tried debugging it the normal way setting break points in my code and attaching to the worker process and also turning on tracing using the crmdiagtool but everything leads me to believe its never firing. I will try debuginng it use the plugin registration tool as you advised. The other thing I will check is registering the plugin on an out of the box action to ensure it fires from a create or an update. Thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks Unlockedluca, your post pointed me in the right direction.It was an issue with the name I had used for the custom action.